# Is there a way to specify a schema for Spark DataFrame, while allowing new fields to be added?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, schema, jsonschema

I have data coming in JSON format. Sometimes some required columns can be missing in the data. I am using a schema to provide the structure of JSON. This fixes missing fields in the nested structure (it adds them with `NULL` values and everything works). However, if there are new columns that are not included in the schema, the read fails.

Is there a way to use the schema only as a way to provide the necessary structure for the work, while allowing some schema drift with new fields that I don't care about?

Edit: I was asked to provide a minimal example, which I will do now:

Let's say I have a schema

```
root
 |-- application_info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- os: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- device_info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bluetooth_enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bluetooth_version: string (nullable = true)
```

This is something I enforce in the data that comes. So if a record comes with only application_info, the schema will enforce device_info with all of the nested structure (with NULLS, so it won't break downstream tasks)

It works fine for this case, but if the record *adds a field*, say, bluetooth_parameters: string, or in my case some field buried deep inside the nesting, then applying the schema for the data will fail.

What I did at first was sampling all of the data, in order to get as complete of a schema as possible, but that either is inefficient or incorrect (depending on how you sample)

What I want is a solution that could tackle both problems of unstructured data

Comment: one option I can think of convert `struct` columns into `map` with this tomorrow if you get any new column in that struct it will be available automatically in `map`

Comment: You can add your schema to your question.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people will be better able to provide help.

Comment: Hello! I've updated the question with an example, but as I was making it in code, I realized that Spark handles it well on its own (more details in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

To my surprise, when I started making the examples, I realized that Spark handles these schema drifts quite well. The only issue I found is if the parent object is missing, it will not recreate the entire nested structure, but will replace it will NULL instead

Sharing the code just in case if anyone wants to try:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, BooleanType, Row
import json
#Schema test
schema = StructType([
    StructField("application_info", StructType([
        StructField("os", StringType(), True),
        StructField("version", StringType(), True)
    ]), True),
    StructField("device_info", StructType([
        StructField("bluetooth_enabled", BooleanType(), True),
        StructField("bluetooth_version", StringType(), True)
    ]), True)
])
record_missing_bt_version = {
    "application_info": {"os": "iOS", "version": "14"} # Device info gets replaced by NULL
}

record_additional_bt_info = {
    "application_info": {"os": "iOS", "version": "14"},
    "device_info": {"bluetooth_enabled": True, "bluetooth_version": "2.0", "bluetooth_parameters": "Bitrate - 2.1MBit/s"} #bluetooth_parameters is not included
}

record_additional_info = {
    "application_info": {"os": "iOS", "version": "14"},
    "device_info": {"bluetooth_enabled": True, "bluetooth_version": "2.0"},
    "other_info": {"Install": "Success"} # other_info Does not get included
}

json_records = [json.dumps(record) for record in [record_missing_bt_version, record_additional_bt_info, record_additional_info]]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(json_records)
df = spark.read.json(rdd, schema=schema)

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+----------------+-----------+
|application_info|device_info|
+----------------+-----------+
|{iOS, 14}       |null       |
|{iOS, 14}       |{true, 2.0}|
|{iOS, 14}       |{true, 2.0}|
+----------------+-----------+
```